# individual page performance in netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7

Hi Iam Chandrashekhar,

Iam using NetBeans 7.2.1. I have facing one problem in this. My jsp file has 4000+ lines. while Iam trying to modifying that file it could be hanged.

can you please any one help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try by reinstalling the net-beans
it will definitely work!!

or

right-click on the toolbar of net-beans7.2.1
add click on Memory to add memory tool on the toolbar
and double-click on that tool to release garbage Collection

Comment: sorry there is no use of by doing this both.